# Using local import instead of installed import

Tags: python, import

I currently have a stable version of APP running on my system. I aim to create a new version of APP but I still need the stable version to run while I do so. I cloned the repository of APP and I encounter the following problem:

Lines of the form `from XXX import YYY` do not import the local file (cloned repo) but imports the ones at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/APP/XXX.py that where created by the stable version.

How can I change that (in VSCode) ?

This question has probably already been asked, but I have been unable to find an answer. If someone could redirect me towards an adequate answer, that would be awesome.

Comment: use a virtualenv to develop your code...?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the APP module from dist-packages.

Comment: But the stable version of APP will not run anymore. Considering that APP is Guake, my main terminal, this would be quite annoying... Especially since this is a side project and I have no clue how long its gonna last.